# How to load CSV dataset with corrupted columns?

Tags: csv, apache-spark

I've exported a client database to a csv file, and tried to import it to Spark using:

```
spark.sqlContext.read
  .format("csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  .load("table.csv")
```

After doing some validations, I find out that some ids were `null` because a column sometimes has a carriage return. And that dislocated all next columns, with a domino effect, corrupting all the data.

What is strange is that when calling `printSchema` the resulting table structure is good.

How to fix the issue?

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data (input and output) that highlight your problem

Comment: You'll need to get back to the export source and work from there. Spark cant deal gracefully with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seemed to have had a lot of luck with `inferSchema` that it worked fine (since it only reads few records to infer the schema) and so `printSchema` gives you a correct result.

Since the CSV export file is broken and assuming you want to process the file using Spark (given its size for example) read it using `textFile` and fix the ids. Save it as CSV format and load it back.

Comment: Unfortunately you are right, there is no way to solve this issue in the import phase.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of spark you are using, but beginning in 2.2 (I believe), there is a 'multiLine' option that can be used to keep fields together that have line breaks in them. From some other things I've read, you may need to apply some quoting and/or escape character options to get it working just how you want it.

```
spark.read
  .csv("table.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .option("inferSchema", "true")
  **.option("multiLine", "true")**
```